# 503 error without maintenance.flag

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I am just starting using developing a module, 
to replace the order view history block and add some message on it.

I made my own block and it works, I refresh a fill time to make sure it wasn't 
just a luck.

But then when I back from my little break, the page just turn 503 and not working again.

I tried `upgrade/clean` and flush cache but it doesn't help.

I do look up from the `var/log` but got nothing.

Do any one know what should I do to this? Because I ready spend a long time on this error.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `.maintenance.flag` in Magento 2

- Delete a file called `.maintenance.flag` from Magento **var** folder
- Remove cache if have: `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: This is a heavy assumption to make. There are plenty of things that could cause a 503 error, especially during the development phase!